# Android Studio slow after Gradle Sync

Tags: android-studio, gradle

After every time I run a Gradle sync, my Android Studio is very slow. Typing is laggy, autocomplete takes a while to show up, etc. The Gradle sync itself runs fine, but when it has finished, everything is slow.

Restarting Android Studio solves the problem, but it's very annoying to do this every time.

Does anyone else have this issue and is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Re-install android studio and change the RAM allocation. if you have 6gb RAM for example you can put your RAM allocation to 5gb or 4gb,the  default is 2gb but sometimes is not enough. and your RAM is 2gb i advice to change your RAM.

Comment: My PC has 24GB RAM, what would you recommend to allocate to AS?